# Not parsing json string in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json

```
var text =  Sheet : [
{"Cell_Address":"A1","Cell_Type":"1","Cell_Value":"Name"},
{"Cell_Address":"B1","Cell_Type":"1","Cell_Value":"Phone no."},
{"Cell_Address":"C1","Cell_Type":"1","Cell_Value":"Currency"},
{"Cell_Address":"D1","Cell_Type":"1","Cell_Value":"Address"},
{"Cell_Address":"A2","Cell_Type":"1","Cell_Value":"Piyush"},
{"Cell_Address":"B2","Cell_TYPE":"0","Cell_Value":"325231234"},
{"Cell_Address":"C2","Cell_TYPE":"0","Cell_Value":"21.0"},
{"Cell_Address":"D2","Cell_Type":"1","Cell_Value":"3361 Route 30 Burbank, IL 60459"},
{"Cell_Address":"A3","Cell_Type":"1","Cell_Value":"Abhishek"},
{"Cell_Address":"B3","Cell_TYPE":"0","Cell_Value":"1235123412"},
{"Cell_Address":"C3","Cell_TYPE":"0","Cell_Value":"23.0"},
{"Cell_Address":"D3","Cell_Type":"1","Cell_Value":"5180 Briarwood Drive Milton, MA 02186"},
{"Cell_Address":"A4","Cell_Type":"1","Cell_Value":"Akhilesh"},
{"Cell_Address":"B4","Cell_TYPE":"0","Cell_Value":"23234123"},
{"Cell_Address":"C4","Cell_TYPE":"0","Cell_Value":"31.0"},
{"Cell_Address":"D4","Cell_Type":"1","Cell_Value":"1258 Spring Street Eden Prairie, MN 55347"},
{"Cell_Address":"A5","Cell_Type":"1","Cell_Value":"aman"},
{"Cell_Address":"B5","Cell_TYPE":"0","Cell_Value":"212351121"},
{"Cell_Address":"C5","Cell_TYPE":"0","Cell_Value":"34.0"},
{"Cell_Address":"D5","Cell_Type":"1","Cell_Value":"6309 Buttonwood Drive Santa Cruz, CA 95060"}
];




for(var i=0 ;i < 20;i++ )
{
    var row = table.insertRow(i+1);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);

    cell1.innerHTML = Sheet[i].Cell_Address;
    cell2.innerHTML = Sheet[i].Cell_Value;      
}
```

This does not give any output

Comment: Not a valid JSON. `Sheet` and its value should be enclosed in curly braces.

Comment: you declared text as an array not a json :) but it is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

Your json isn't a valid json object, you're missing `{}`, I modified your script to better demonstrate your problem and how to solve it :) Please check the code below. Notice I also use `text.Sheet.length` instead of a fixed number of `20` so it could loop to the end of the object

```js
var text = { Sheet : [
{"Cell_Address":"A1","Cell_Type":"1","Cell_Value":"Name"},
{"Cell_Address":"B1","Cell_Type":"1","Cell_Value":"Phone no."},
{"Cell_Address":"C1","Cell_Type":"1","Cell_Value":"Currency"},
{"Cell_Address":"D1","Cell_Type":"1","Cell_Value":"Address"},
{"Cell_Address":"A2","Cell_Type":"1","Cell_Value":"Piyush"},
{"Cell_Address":"B2","Cell_TYPE":"0","Cell_Value":"325231234"},
{"Cell_Address":"C2","Cell_TYPE":"0","Cell_Value":"21.0"},
{"Cell_Address":"D2","Cell_Type":"1","Cell_Value":"3361 Route 30 Burbank, IL 60459"},
{"Cell_Address":"A3","Cell_Type":"1","Cell_Value":"Abhishek"},
{"Cell_Address":"B3","Cell_TYPE":"0","Cell_Value":"1235123412"},
{"Cell_Address":"C3","Cell_TYPE":"0","Cell_Value":"23.0"},
{"Cell_Address":"D3","Cell_Type":"1","Cell_Value":"5180 Briarwood Drive Milton, MA 02186"},
{"Cell_Address":"A4","Cell_Type":"1","Cell_Value":"Akhilesh"},
{"Cell_Address":"B4","Cell_TYPE":"0","Cell_Value":"23234123"},
{"Cell_Address":"C4","Cell_TYPE":"0","Cell_Value":"31.0"},
{"Cell_Address":"D4","Cell_Type":"1","Cell_Value":"1258 Spring Street Eden Prairie, MN 55347"},
{"Cell_Address":"A5","Cell_Type":"1","Cell_Value":"aman"},
{"Cell_Address":"B5","Cell_TYPE":"0","Cell_Value":"212351121"},
{"Cell_Address":"C5","Cell_TYPE":"0","Cell_Value":"34.0"},
{"Cell_Address":"D5","Cell_Type":"1","Cell_Value":"6309 Buttonwood Drive Santa Cruz, CA 95060"}
]};



var table = document.getElementById("table");
for(var i=0 ;i < text.Sheet.length;i++ )
{
    var row = table.insertRow(i+1);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);

    cell1.innerHTML = text.Sheet[i].Cell_Address;
    cell2.innerHTML = text.Sheet[i].Cell_Value;      
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr></tr>
 </table>
```